# iOS get the XML attributes using NSXMLParser

Tags: ios, nsxmlparser

IOS get the XML attributes using NSXMLParser

Hi Guys,

I have a XML that looks like this:

```
<Rows>
<RowOne SKATERID="706" MANUFACTURER="A-DZG" ISFACT="F" ISSKATE="F"> True</RowOne>
<RowTwo SKATERID="318" MANUFACTURER="A-FGW" ISFACT="F" ISSKATE="T"/> True</RowTwo>
<RowThree SKATERID="458" MANUFACTURER="A-OPJ" ISFACT="F" ISSKATE="T"/> False</RowThree>
<RowThree SKATERID="178" MANUFACTURER="A-JSL" ISFACT="F" ISSKATE="T"/> True</RowThree>
.
.
.
</Rows>
```

Any of you knows how get I get the attributes of each node such as SKATERID,MANUFACTURER,ISFACT,ISSKATE ?

I'll really appreciate your help

Answer (score 0):

Using the NSXMLParserDelegate you want to grab attributes in didStartElement

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict
{
  NSString *SKATERID = [attributeDict objectForKey:@"SKATERID"];
  NSString *MANUFACTURER = [attributeDict objectForKey:@"MANUFACTURER"];
  .
  .
  .
}
```